# Disable next page on uiGrid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I am using **external pagination** with **ui-grid** and **angularjs**.

The server has **70 items** mocked at the moment, but I will not know the items count from the server.
The **pageSize is set to 50**.

So it should have 2 pages (one with 50 items on it and one with 20).

The button for **next page** is **NOT disabled** on the second page but on the third one when there are no items in the grid to show.

**I would like it disabled on the second page!**

Link to the plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/OuM8lN0R06Xudn1frLax?p=preview

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.pagination']);

app.service('foo', ['$q', function ($q) {
    var items = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 70; i++) {
        items.push({
            "firstName": "firstName" + i,
            "lastName": "lastName" + i,
            "company": "company" + i,
            "employed": i % 4 === 0
        });
    }

    this.bar = function (page, pageSize) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var start = (page - 1) * pageSize;
        deferred.resolve(items.slice(start, start + pageSize));

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return this;
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', '$timeout', 'uiGridConstants', 'foo', function ($scope, $http, $log, $timeout, uiGridConstants, foo) {
    var paginationOptions = {
        pageNumber: 1,
        pageSize: 50,
        sort: null
    };

    $scope.selectedIds = [];

    $scope.gridOptions = getOptions();

    function getOptions() {
        return {
            enableHorizontalScrollbar: 0,
            enableVerticalScrollbar: 2,

            enableRowSelection: true,
            enableFullRowSelection: true,
            multiSelect: true,

            paginationPageSizes: [50, 100],
            paginationPageSize: 50,
            useExternalPagination: true,

            onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
                $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
                getPage(1, 50);

                gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged($scope, function (newPage, pageSize) {
                    paginationOptions.pageNumber = newPage;
                    paginationOptions.pageSize = pageSize;
                    getPage(newPage, pageSize);
                });
            }
        };
    }

    function getPage(page, pageSize) {
        foo.bar(page, pageSize)
            .then(function (data) {
                $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
                $scope.gridOptions.totalItems = undefined;
            });
    }

    getPage(1, 50);
}]);
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div class="grid" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-selection></div>
    </div>


    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it using a simple change in the **getPage(page, pageSize)** method.

Here is the code for the method:

```
function getPage(page, pageSize) {
    foo.bar(page, pageSize)
        .then(function (data) {
            $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
            $scope.gridOptions.totalItems = data.length === pageSize ? undefined : (page - 1) * pageSize + data.length;
        });
}
```

Here is the working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/8EM0HPFZr4Corud9oADR?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the value if `gridOptions.totalItems`, in your case 70. This is how ui-grid figures out how many pages to show. I've updated your [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2mKdGDx4u8nOp2P7eJkp?p=preview) to reflect the changes.

Comment: I am aware that it can be handled with **gridOptions.totalServerItems**, but the thing is that I like to disable that button by force, because otherwise it will just wait for empty response.

Comment: After looking through the source code, it seems like setting `gridOptions.useCustomPagination` to true would achieve the desired results. ui-gird documentation suggests the following when setting `useCustomPagination` to true: "When true, handle the `paginationChanged` event and set `data`, `firstRowIndex`, `lastRowIndex`, and `totalItems`."